# exponent difference of floating points

Tags: numbers

for example we have two floating point numbers
task is calculate exponent diffrence or `e_x-e_y`     what means  exponent difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the specification for IEEE-754 floating point numbers.  Wikipedia has a [description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).  Your professor probably wants you to determine the exponential components of the floats you're working with and compute the integer difference between them.